# How does javascript regex handle new line

Tags: javascript, regex, exec, global

Why the following code only give me "abc" instead of "abc\nef"? How does the regex handle the new line? Thanks.

```
    var input = "abc\nef",
    pattern = /.*/g,
    result = pattern.exec(input),
    i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log(result[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript you need to use `[\s\S]` to match any character (including newline) since dot don't match newline and Javascript doesn't have a `s` (DOTALL) regex switch.

So if you use:

```
/[\s\S]*/.exec("abc\nef");
```

You will get:

```
["abc
ef"]
```